# Create Datetime and add milliseconds

Tags: date-and-time

I want to create a datetime with milliseconds in the form:

```
"2023.07.22 12:34:56.123";
```

To which I can add a certain amount of milliseconds (e.g. with the `DatePlus` Function) and from there create a table with datetimes:

```
DateObject[{2023, 7, 22, 12, 34, 56}]
```

works,but adding milliseconds does not

```
DateObject[{2023, 7, 22, 12, 34, 56,123}]
```

At this point, I'm a little bit lost and need some help. I'm using Mathematica 12.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the smallest date unit is the second, you can still provide fractions of seconds:

```
DateObject[{2023, 7, 22, 12, 34, 56.123}]
```

Also with DatePlus:

```
DatePlus[someDate, {.123, "Second"}]
```

Or use Quantity:

```
DatePlus[someDate, Quantity[123, "Milliseconds"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that dates only have a resolution of sec.

You must change to millisec, e.g. using AbsoluteTime and multiply by 10^3, then add the chosen amount of millisec and change back to DateTime. This gives you a resolution of sec, not millisec:

```
date= DateObject[{2023, 7, 22, 12, 34, 56}];
abstime= 10^3 AbsoluteTime[date]

3899018096000
```

Now add some millisec, e.g. 10^5, divide by 10^3 and change back to dateTime:

```
DateList[abstime/1000 + 10^5

{2023, 7, 23, 16, 21, 36.}
```